# What are some patters for designing REST API for user-based platform in AWS?

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am trying to shift towards serverless architecture when it comes to building REST API. I came from Ruby on Rails background.

I have successfully understood and adapted services such as Api Gateway, Cognito, RDS and Lambda functions, however I am struggling with putting it all together in optimal way.

My case is the following. I have a simple user based platform when there are multiple resources related to application members say blog application.

I have used Cognito for the sake of authentication and Aurora as the database service for keeping thing like articles and likes..

Since the database and Cognito user pool are decoupled, it is hard for me to do things like:

Fetching users that liked particular article

Fetching users comments

It seems problematic for me because I need to pass some unique Cognito user identifier (retrieved during authorization phase in API gateway) to lambda function which will then save the database record with an external reference to this user. On the other hand, If I were to fetch particular users, firstly I must fetch their identifiers from my relation database and then request users details from Cognito user pool..I lack some standard ways of accessing current user in my lambda functions as well as mechanisms for easily associating databse record with that user..

I have not found some convincing recommended patterns for designing such applications even though it seems like a very common problem and I am having hard time struggling if my approach is correct..

I would appreciate some comments on what are some patterns to consider when designing simple user based platform and what are the pitfalls of my solution. Any articles and examples will also be very helpfull.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

These sound like standard problems associated with distributed, indpependent, databases. You can no longer delegate all relationships to the database and get a result aggregating them in some way. You have to do the work yourself by calling one database, then the other.

For a case like this:

> Fetching users that liked particular article

You would look up the "likes" database to determine user IDs of those who liked it, then look up the "users" database to determine user details such as name and avatar.

Most patterns follow standard database advice, e.g. in the above example, you could follow the performance-oriented pattern of **de-normalising** - store user data such as name and avatar against each "like", as long as you feel the extra storage and burden of keeping it consistent is justified by the reduction in queries (probably too many Likes to justify this).

Another important practice is using bulk queries to avoid N+1 queries. This is what Rails does with the `includes` syntax, but you may have to do it yourself here. In my example, it should only take two queries because the second query should get all required user data in one go, by querying for users matching the *list* of user IDs.

Finally, I'd suggest you try to abstract things. This kind of code gets messy fast, so be sure to build a well-encapsulated data layer that isolates application code from dealing with the mess of multiple databases.